# Dropdown list allow multi-select in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a trouble that : I have to implement a webpart contain a Field that look up into other list. But the requirement that it must allow multi-value, and multi-select as a dropdown-list.

Pls, help me :(

Answer (score 0):

The data side is easy enough, use a multilookup field.

In a web part, the UI is standard .net/javascript and can be pretty much anything you have a consistent set of rules for. That is your real problem - if your client won't accept any of the standard methods of multiselect (checkboxlist, ctrl-click in a listbox or moving items between listboxes), get them to explain the details of how they want the dropdown to work.